# Concatenate various dropdownlists in single date format in an XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, drop-down-menu

I have three separate dropdown menus namely - mm, dd, yyyy - defining the date format. Now I want the values selected in each of the list to be concatenated in the "**mm-dd-yyyy**" format.

This is my front-end code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpmm" runat="server" CssClass="drp1">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdte" runat="server" CssClass="drp1">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpyyyy" runat="server" CssClass="drp1">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want these values to be saved in the provided format in an XML file. How exactly am I suppose to go through the concatenation of the values selected in each of the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = string.Join("-", drpmm.SelectedItem.Text, 
                            drpdte.SelectedItem.Text,
                            drpyyyy.SelectedItem.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string finalDate = drpmm.SelectedItem.Text + "-" + drpdte.SelectedItem.Text + "-"
 + drpyyyy.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: and how would I display this date in an xml tree structure? I'm using XmlDocuments. E.g. `XmlElement ginfo = doc.CreateElement("General_Info");
            ginfo.InnerText = strGInfo;
            root.AppendChild(ginfo);`

Comment: are you asking how to insert values into an XML file? Because i think that's an entirely different question ;).

Comment: I want to concatenate the values selected first and then insert the new value as whole and display it in an XML file. Is it different? :P

Comment: i dont understand what you are asking, in my answer "finaleDate" *is* a concatenation of all the dropdownlists. if you want to insert that date into your XML then the string **finalDate** should do :)

Comment: so how would i display this finalDate in my XML document? Should i use innertext or just simply display the output?

Comment: how do you insert the other values into your XML document? can you show some of your codebehind file?

Comment: that's in the first comment i made. `XmlElement ginfo = doc.CreateElement("General_Info"); ginfo.InnerText = strGInfo; root.AppendChild(ginfo);`

Comment: that's a different thing. it's a part of the code i'm working on, where ginfo is an alphanumeric string entered in a text field. the finalDate is separated into 3 different dropdown menus mm-dd-yyyy.

Comment: lol i seriously dont understand what you are asking for anymore. have you *tried* my answer? if you did, you would see that finalDate is going to be something like "05-07-1990" (depends on what you select in the dropdowns ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you create a DateTime type object using Constructor [`DateTime(year, month, day)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx) and then you can format the object using ToString, you can also use it later in your code if you need a `DateTime` type object. Later you can format it:

```
DateTimeObject.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string dtStr = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",drpyyyy.SelectedValue,drpdte.SelectedValue.PadLeft(2,'0'),drpmm.SelectedValue.PadLeft(2,'0');
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dtStr);
dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
     String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
     String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
     String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
     String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
     String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
     String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
     String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
     String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
     String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

for more info [stringformat](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)